Magento 2 how can he create a configurable product with a selection of attributes?
Please, how can he create a configurable product with a selection of attributes? (by manual selection)
The point is that I need to select a parameter for each configuration that it should meet. (not every variat has the same parameter)
I need to select from attributes:
Example:
T-shirt:
Size
XS
Color only blue
Size
S
Color only green
Size
L
The color is red
Sometimes I need to add 3 attributes.
Something like this:
Model: XS    Color: Blue        Width: 30
Model:  S    Color: green      Width: 50
Model: L     Color: Red        Width: 70
The generator will automatically create each color from each size.
I have products with 25 combinations.
When it creates 25 configurations from each combination and I have to delete 24 of them for each combination, it's complicated
I would need to choose which attribute should have which product.
Can you advise me how to reduce it?
Thank you
